# SQL Server CTE query syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I get this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

from this query:

```
seq = row_number() over 
(
  partition by t.CustID
  order by t.InvoiceID, 
           t.Date,
           CASE WHEN t.S_Type = 'Receipt Voucher' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
 )

;

WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT  CustID,
        [InvoiceID],
        S_Type,
        DATE,
        Debit,
        Credit,
        seq = row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CustID
            ORDER BY InvoiceID,
                DATE,
                CASE 
                    WHEN S_Type = 'Receipt Voucher'
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 2
                    END
            )
    FROM Statement
    )
SELECT c.[InvoiceID],
    c.S_Type AS Type,
    c.DATE,
    c.Debit,
    c.Credit,
    b.Balance
FROM cte c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT Balance = SUM(Debit) - SUM(Credit)
    FROM cte AS x
    WHERE x.CustID = c.CustID
        AND x.seq <= c.seq
    ) b
WHERE c.CustID = '48'
    AND DATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01'
        AND '2016-01-01'
ORDER BY seq
```

I have tried to add select in-front of seq I get these errors:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "t.CustID" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The multi-part identifier "t.InvoiceID" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   The multi-part identifier "t.Date" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   The multi-part identifier "t.S_Type" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
>   The multi-part identifier ".Debit" could not be bound.

Comment: I'm confused by the code you've posted.   Are you actually executing the fragment above `WITH cte`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a fragment of code at the beginning of your request `seq=...` which is invalid. Your query can use the *seq* calculated in the cte.

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT  CustID,
        [InvoiceID],
        S_Type,
        DATE,
        Debit,
        Credit,
        seq = row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CustID
            ORDER BY InvoiceID,
            DATE,
            CASE 
                WHEN S_Type = 'Receipt Voucher'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 2
                END
            )
    FROM Statement
    )
SELECT c.[InvoiceID],
    c.S_Type AS Type,
    c.DATE,
    c.Debit,
    c.Credit,
    b.Balance
FROM cte c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT Balance = SUM(Debit) - SUM(Credit)
    FROM cte AS x
    WHERE x.CustID = c.CustID
        AND x.seq <= c.seq
    ) b
WHERE c.CustID = '48'
    AND DATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01'
    AND '2016-01-01'

ORDER BY c.seq;
```

There was also a missing **c** before Debit.

With thanks to a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: i still get errors can you provide full code may be i applied it wrongly

Comment: @Ayman I edited my answer and corrected another little problem

Comment: thanks but still i have the issue error msg "t.CustID,t.InvoiceID,t.Date,t.S_Type" could not be bound

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to use a window function in the `order by` clause (and you don't need it, as you can use the `seq` column from the CTE)

Comment: I edited my answer again following the good advice from a_horse_with_no_name